# Convert CSV to restructured JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV File with following contents:

source: [data.opennepal.net](https://github.com/opennepal/odp-disaster/blob/master/Causalities%20caused%20by%20earthquake%2C2015/data.csv)

```
District,Zone,Geographical Region,Development Region,Causalities,In Number
Sindhupalchok,Bagmati,Mountain,Central,Total No. of Houses,66688
Sindhupalchok,Bagmati,Mountain,Central,Total Population,287798
Sindhupalchok,Bagmati,Mountain,Central,Dead Male,1497
Sindhupalchok,Bagmati,Mountain,Central,Dead Female,1943
Kathmandu,Bagmati,Hill,Central,Total No. of Houses,436344
Kathmandu,Bagmati,Hill,Central,Total Population,1744240
Kathmandu,Bagmati,Hill,Central,Dead Male,621
Kathmandu,Bagmati,Hill,Central,Dead Female,600
```

My objective is to generate a JSON object like this from it:

```
{
  "district":{
    "Sindhupalchok":{
      "Causalities":{
        "Total No. of Houses":66688,
        "Total Population":287798,
        "Dead Male":1497,
        "Dead Female":1943
      },
      "geoInfo":{
        "Zone":"Bagmati",
        "geography":"Mountain",
        "Dev Region":"Central"
      }
    },
    "Kathmandu":{
      "Causalities":{
        "Total No. of Houses":436344,
        "Total Population":1744240,
        "Dead Male":621,
        "Dead Female":600
      },
      "geoInfo":{
        "Zone":"Bagmati",
        "geography":"Hill",
        "Dev Region":"Central"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames) but it generates redundant nodes in JSON which is difficult to parse and unnecessarily lenghty.

I am using python 2.x 
This is my attempt so far:

```
>>> csvData = open('data.csv','rb')
>>> fieldnames = ("district", "zone", "geographicalRegion", "developmentRegion", "causalities", "injuredNumber")
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(csvData, fieldnames)
>>> rawJson = json.dumps([ row for row in reader ])
```

rawJson isn't the one I've been seeking. It just maps the fieldnames with individual datasets.

So the question is: How can I create this JSON object without redundant nodes?

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: @glibdud I've added the code I've tried.

Comment: Since the CSV and JSON data don't have any sort of 1:1 relationship, you're going to need to loop over the CSV data and build the structure a bit more manually. Just build it as a dict and then dump it as JSON in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As glibdud mentions in the comments you need to loop over the data a bit more manually, so that you can create the desired JSON structure.

We read each line of the CSV data as a `dict`, and check if we've encountered a new district, and if so we create a new `data` `dict` for it, and insert a `geoInfo` `dict` into `data`. Then we can gather the casualty data from that line and the subsequent lines for that district. And once we've gathered all that data we can insert the `data` `dict` into the main `all_data` `dict`.

To test the code I put your .csv data into a file called 'qdata.csv'

```
import csv
import json

filename = 'qdata.csv'
fieldnames = ('district', 'Zone', 'geography', 
    'Dev Region', 'casualties', 'injured')

geo_keys = ('Zone', 'geography', 'Dev Region')

all_data = {}
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    # skip header
    next(reader)
    current_district = None
    for row in reader:
        district = row['district']
        if district != current_district:
            current_district = district
            data = all_data[district] = {}
            casualties = data['Casualties'] = {}
            data['geoInfo'] = dict((k, row[k]) for k in geo_keys)
        casualties[row['casualties']] = row['injured']

print json.dumps(all_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

#### Output

```
{
    "Kathmandu": {
        "Casualties": {
            "Dead Female": "600", 
            "Dead Male": "621", 
            "Total No. of Houses": "436344", 
            "Total Population": "1744240"
        }, 
        "geoInfo": {
            "Dev Region": "Central", 
            "Zone": "Bagmati", 
            "geography": "Hill"
        }
    }, 
    "Sindhupalchok": {
        "Casualties": {
            "Dead Female": "1943", 
            "Dead Male": "1497", 
            "Total No. of Houses": "66688", 
            "Total Population": "287798"
        }, 
        "geoInfo": {
            "Dev Region": "Central", 
            "Zone": "Bagmati", 
            "geography": "Mountain"
        }
    }
}
```

This output isn't *exactly* what you've got in your question, but I think you should be able to take it from here. :)

Comment: It isn't exactly as in the question. But, I find your JSON more awesome that what I've asked. Thank you so much. I will be able to take it from here. If I get stuck, StackOverflow is here ;)